# will_paginate's per_page limit not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't figure out why the :per_page limit does not work for surf_school_reviews. It still shows all the reviews although I set the :per_page limit (I just set it to 2 so that I won't have to create many reviews just to test if it works). I am confident that all my associations  and codes are correct as shown below. But I have not encountered any problems when will_page is used for surf_schools.

I am sorry if my description is not clear, so you can just comment and clarify so that I can explain it further to you.

> surf_schools_controller.rb

```
def show
 @surf_school = SurfSchool.find(params[:id])
 @surf_school_reviews = @surf_school.surf_school_reviews.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 2)
end
```

> surf_school.rb

```
belongs_to :user
has_many   :surf_school_reviews
```

> surf_school_review.rb

```
belongs_to :surf_school
belongs_to :user
```

> user.rb

```
has_many :surf_schools,        dependent: :destroy
has_many :surf_school_reviews, dependent: :destroy
```

> routes.rb

```
resources :surf_schools do
 resources :surf_school_reviews, except: [:index, :show]
end
```

Comment: @surf_school_reviews = SurfSchoolReview.where(:surf_school_id => @surf_school.id).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 2)   try this code

Comment: I tried your code but it doesn't work. By the way, I edited my post and added my code in routes.rb, it may help.

Comment: could you check if perhaps, you've set the per_page property on the `surf_school_reviews`

Answer (score 0):

You have to include below code in your show.html:

```
<%= paginate @surf_school_reviews, param_name: 'page' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your action try like this :

```
@surf_school_reviews = @surf_school.surf_school_reviews.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 2)
```

You have to use like this in your show.html.erb file.
Use it at the end of your div .

```
<% unless @surf_school_reviews.blank? %>
    <%= will_paginate @surf_school_reviews,   renderer:BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
<% end %>
```